# Grails using a package to hold domain classes

Tags: grails

Grails question: Confused about using a package to hold domain classes.

I'm using Netbeans on Mac to check out Grails.

When I create domain classes without using a package holding it, I can just go to `localhost:8080/gTunes` and the expected `.gsp` page is rendered properly.

However when I use a package  (`com.g2one.gtunes`) to hold a domain class (`Song`), I don't see the `.gsp` page when I go to `localhost:8080/gTunes`.  Instead I see a Directory view of folders/files such as  `META-INF`, `WEB-INF`, etc.  In order to see the expected `.gsp` page, I have to type in the specific URL  `localhost:8080/gTunes/index.gsp`

In my research I've seen people talk about adding the following line but I can't figure out where to add it.

```
<%@page import="path.to.domains.*"%>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: consider using packages and when you create the controller, use com.g2one.gtunes.Song and the import will be added for you for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why I way I was having this issue. I'm going through Definitive Guide to Grails 2nd Edt  on mac with NetBeans.  I ran into this problem when I

- created 'gtunes' project at `/Users/name/NetBeans/gtunes`
- deleted 'gtunes' project and `/Users/name/NetBeans/gtunes`
- created another project with same name at `/Users/name/NetBeans/gtunes`.  I type in some code and run it and I run into the error I posted.

To get around this error,

- I create 'gtunes' project located at `/Users/name/NetBeans/gtunes`
- I right click on 'gtunes' project in NetBeans, issue 'Clean' command.  Than I see some files are removed from `~/.grails/...`  in Output window
- I right click on Album.groovy (possibly Song.groovy also) and issue 'Generate Views', NOT 'Generate All'
- Run the project and it works!

Thanks all for comments and hopefully my mistake will help others avoid same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that import to the top of your GSP pages that use the domain class that you put in a package.  Don't forget you'll also need an import in your controllers unless that are in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Add the specified line as the very first line in the GSP you are trying to render (show).